# How to configure Oracle JDK for Websphere?

Tags: websphere, java-7, websphere-8

I want to integrate Oracle's JDK with IBM WebSphere Application Server instead of the default installed IBM JDK. If possible, how to do I configure WebSphere so that it makes use of Oracle JDK?

Comment: Can you share any link to refer. I need to run IBM WAS 8.5.5 with Oracle Jdk.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but I'm curious why you need to run with Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

It is not supported. You have to use Java that comes with WebSphere Application Server. Oracle Java is only supported for WebSphere Liberty profile. However since WAS 8.5.5 you can either use IBM Java SDK 6 or IBM Java SDK 7.

Comment: Does the Liberty profile have full length features & functionality when compared with other  WebSphere AS profile that are created (for ex APPserver1). can i use Liberty profile for production.

Comment: @kusumat Here is list with [Liberty features](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-0-2-2-0&lang=en). It is certified with Java EE 6 Web profile (doesn't have all features of full Java EE, e.g. remote EJB, but from the other hand it already has some features from Java EE 7, like web sockets). Yes you can use Liberty for both development (free) and production (paid license, unless you already have WebSphere licenses). Any reason why you want to switch to Oracle JDK?

Comment: Update to the previous comment - starting from WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.6 it is fully Java EE 7 compatible.